# How do you include Spring Boot Actuator with SB 2.1 and not have all endpoints locked under security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I literally can't figure this out and have been through a dozen answers and none of them work. What exactly is the configuration to stop the redirect to login? I'd prefer to leave my actuator endpoints behind security but I honestly don't care either way at this point because I need this application to be usable.

Answer (score 0):

There’s an example of the configuration that is required in Spring Boot’s [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-security):

```
@Configuration
public class ActuatorSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Security configuration for a [Spring Webflux](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html) service to allow access to actuator endpoints:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.authorizeExchange()
                // .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable().build();
    }
}
```